# Authorization setting in SAM for AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

Attempting to deploy an API through SAM with an attached Lambda Authorizer. Once deployed the authorizer is successfully created on the API under "Authorizers", however the setting for Authorization on the resource is still set as NONE despite the authorizer being available for selection in the drop down.

[Authorization setting on resource set as NONE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R570F.png)

[Authorizer created under Authorizers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6ddv.png)

```
Resources:
  PlatformApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: API Gateway name
      StageName: !Sub ${Environment}
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          LambdaTokenAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: FunctionArn Name
      DefinitionBody:
        'Fn::Transform':
          Name: 'AWS::Include'
          Parameters:
            Location: !Sub s3://${OpenApiLocation}

  
  PlatformApiAuthorizer:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Authorizer
    Properties:
      AuthorizerUri: AuthorizerUri
      IdentitySource: method.request.header.auth
      Name: AuthorizerName
      RestApiId: !Ref PlatformApiGateway
      Type: TOKEN
```

The APIAuth attribute appears to be the location of these settings, however following these docs doesn't include attributes that set this setting of Authorization

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-apiauth.html

What SAM attributes am I missing in my API definition to have that setting set with the relevant authorizer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Paste lambda ARN which provides authorization for the API.

FunctionArn: `FunctionArn Name`

In [LambdaTokenAuthorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-api-lambdatokenauthorizer.html#sam-api-lambdatokenauthorizer-functionarn) check FunctionArn.

Good to paste in your question list of Resources from Cloudformation output.